# Synchronized DE Filter - Contact without Channel Address

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contact, data-synchronization, mobilestudio

There are 45k records as 'Contact without Channel Address' in my client org. I am aware that these can be deleted from MC and accordingly filter can be applied on Sync DE to prevent the flow again to MC. But the challenge I am facing is, the filter which I used to create a list for 'Contact without Channel Address' records has 3 filters( EmailAddress And MobileNumber And DeviceID = NUll) as we are using Mobile Studio .The sync DE doesn't provide selection of multiple filter.
Also the device ID gets created in MC and cant be managed through Sales cloud --> Sync DE. How can I manage these records in order to minimize the contact count as these are not being used .

*People downvoting it, a response would have been helpful